# Веб-сервер на виртуальной машине

Tags: сервер

Здравствуйте. Можно ли установить веб-сервер на виртуальную машину (VMware)и подключить его к общему сетевому окружению? Интересует сервер на freeBSD или Ubuntu server. Хочу создать сервер для теста сайтов.

Comment: Можно. Всё зависит от dhcp и dns серверов.

Comment: upd: Нужен доступ к ftp и видимость сайта с основной ОС.

Comment: Если нужен доступ только с основной машины - так тут вообще проблем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, для этого у VMWare и Hyper-V есть соответствующие настройки виртуальной сети. То что вас интересует (в самом простом варианте) выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нам необходимо "мостовое" соединение, и виртуальная машина будет видна в сети наравне с остальными.
Для того чтобы ваш виртуальный сервер был виден из интернета необходимо настроить ваш роутер (DMZ или форвардинг портов, чтобы выйти за пределы NAT)